# Connection between windows 2012r2 DC and ADC

Tags: networking, site-to-site-vpn

I have a head office and a number of suboffices. Both head office and suboffices need to access some corporate server, which is physically in the head office. But suboffices should not be able to access head office or each other. Suboffices are at the substantial distance of each other and from the head office (many kms).

I have knowledge of servers and I have created a site on my domain controller also which is head office but the problem is the additional domain controller we have is on another site which is very far from head office,I know how to creates site in server but dont have any idea of how can I connect that site with another site using public IP.

Comment: "I am new with servers and dont know how do I do this," Hire someone who can read the manual and does so. This is not the place - per site rules - where you come NOT reading manuals at all and have us do your work.

Comment: It's not about manuals Tom, anyway thanks for your reply.

Comment: Actually it is. For example. what is the difference between DC and ADC in your world? And it isa trivial setup IF you ahve routing in place. "Just do it" style - if you know how to add a domain controller. Which is manual level knowledge.

Comment: Tom, I have knowledge of servers and I have created a site on my domain controller also which is head office but the problem is the additional domain controller we have is on another site which is very far from head office,I know how to creates site in server but dont have any idea of how can I connect that site with another site using public IP, thats the only reason I come here thinking that may be I get some help here, I want to create a new setup which requires network and firewall knowledge and I am lacking in that, thats the reason I am here looking for some help, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Ah, so it is not an active diretory question but one about basic networking on the internet and VPN? See, HIRE A PRO. You obviously do not manage to explain the problem an never learned how to actually describe it properly. You totally borked that - down to your tag.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's my mistake, I have to elaborate the problem properly, anyway thanks for correcting me.

Comment: You obviously does not have even the most basic networking knowledge to successfully setup a site-to-site vpn. You should hire a professional as TomTom said or contact your ISP. Most ISPs are offering  some kind of site2site VPN services for their clients.

Comment: You @bcs78 should atleast read the edited question first before giving your judgement.

Comment: "I want to create a new setup which requires network and firewall knowledge and I am lacking in that". I appologize I didn't want to judge you but you've declared that fact. I just wanted to point out that if you don't have networking knowledge then there is an option to contact your ISP and ask them that do they have any VPN solution you can subscribe to.

Comment: `suboffices should not be able to access head office or each other.` That will not work for domain controller replication.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone specially@TomTom I got the solution from one of my friend, actually he guide me how to do that rather giving me advice to hire a pro..now atleast I know how this can be done without any pro help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the ISP may restrict SMTP traffic which is needed for the replication to happen between two DCs away from each other.  So, you should rule out the possibility of connecting over Public IP.  Setup a S2S VPN between DC location and then you can move ahead with replication and have your DCs communicate to each other